# List of questions comparison

Tags: sql

I have a profile that looks like this:

```
profile_id | answer_id
----------------------
1                1
1                4
1               10
```

I have a table which contains a list of responses by poll respondents with structure like this:

```
user_id | answer_id
-------------------
1            1
1            9
2            1
2            4
2           10
3           14
3           29
```

How do I select a list of users that gave all of the answers in the profile?  In this case only user 2.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select user_id
from response r
where answer_id in (select distinct answer_id  -- get the list of distinct answer_id
                    from profile
                    where profile_id = 1)  -- add filter if needed
group by user_id  -- group by each user
having count(distinct answer_id) = (select count(distinct answer_id)  -- verify the user has the distinct count
                                    from profile
                                    where profile_id = 1)  -- add filter if needed
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f3d9/2)

Or another way to write this is:

```
select user_id
from response r
where answer_id in (1, 4, 10)
group by user_id
having count(distinct answer_id) = 3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f3d9/3)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a join query with an aggregation:

```
select a.user_id
from profile p full outer join
     answers a
     on p.answer_id = p.answer_id and
        p.profile_id = 1
group by a.user_id
having count(p.profileid) = count(*) and
       count(a.user_id) = count(*)
```

The full outer join matches all the profiles to all the answers.  If the two sets completely match, then there are no "null"s in the ids of the other set.  The `having` clause checks for jsut this condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM user_answer 
WHERE user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM profile WHERE answer_id = 1) AND
      user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM profile WHERE answer_id = 4) AND
      user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM profile WHERE answer_id = 10)
```

Comment: This is horrible... Why not use a JOIN? I should clarify. You're doing 3 separate index scans of USER_ID for no reason whatsoever. You can use 1.

Comment: KISS = Keep It Simple Stupid :)

Comment: Hmmm, it's a valid argument ;-). But I'm not sure it works in databases where efficiency is normally everything...

Comment: Why to make a rocket if all you need is to kill one wasp :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN table2
         ON table1.answer_id = table2.answer_id
WHERE  table2.user_id = 2
```

i think this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: That doesn't return users that answered **all** questions.